# Does a like statement attract a SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does a like statement as mentioned below create any security issue or SQL injection.
And, if yes, how to mitigate the risk?

The below script will be executed inside a stored procedure; what is the recommend approach to use a `like` query?

This code snippet is copied from a parameterized stored procedure.

```
declare @args varchar(100) ='SID%' -- start with
-- set @args ='SID01' -- exact match
-- set @args ='%%' -- all
-- set @args = '%VV%' -- contains
-- set @args ='SID%' -- start with
-- set @args ='%JUN' -- end with
select * from Employee e where e.LastName like @args
```

Comment: There is no *"script below"*. You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54512070/edit) function to add it to your question

Comment: The recommended approach concerning the SQL injections is to use parameterized queries in your application

Comment: This code snippet copied from a Parameterized store procedure.

Comment: You are safe from SQL Injection Vulnerability if `@args` is a parameter to the `SP`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use typed variables as parameters in your SQL you are safe from SQL Injection attacks.
SQL Injection works when the attacker can gain access to dynamic SQL.

This is unsafe:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(50)=N'select * from Employee e where e.LastName like '''+@args+''''
EXEC sys.sp_executesql  @sql
```

This is safe:

```
select * from Employee e where e.LastName like @args
```